# org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess.getContainer(Lorg/apache/tiles/request/ApplicationContext;)Lorg/apache/tiles/TilesContainer;]

Tags: java, spring, tiles-3

I am  using spring 4 and tiles 3 integration .

Configuration in spring.xml file as below :

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>           
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">      
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
</bean>
```

For Spring :  spring 4.1.7.and relevant jars

For tiles :   Tiles 3.0.5 jars and relevant jars

Please find the below error  : I was getting at server start up :

```
Dez 07, 2015 9:05:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
        SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet [mccstore] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'standard_welcome':
        n is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess.getContainer(Lorg/apache/tiles/request/ApplicationContext;)Lorg/apache/tiles/TilesContainer;] with root cause
        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess.getContainer(Lorg/apache/tiles/request/ApplicationContext;)Lorg/apache/tiles/TilesContainer;
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.afterPropertiesSet(TilesView.java:97)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:399)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.applyLifecycleMethods(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:487)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.loadView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:482)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.createView(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:244)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.createView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:446)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:156)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1283)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1224)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1
```

Comment: Check your dependencies you are mixing incompatible versions, also you don't  need to specify the `viewClass` property of the `TilesViewResolver` that is set already for you.

Comment: Thanks Deinum , I was having some tile2.2.2 versions jars were also thr. SO, i removed that after that I am getting below error :java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess.getContainer(TilesAccess.java:124)
Any idea ?? Thanks in advance!!